# Hypothesises testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I want to test a hypothesis saying 50%  of employees in a company are happy. A survey of 100 people has been made and 41 say that they are happy.
My questions: I can't understand what I am given.
(1) Is the hypothesis $H_0: \mu_0 = 50$ $H_1:\mu_1 \ne 50$?
(2) Do I have a standard deviation $\sigma$?
(3) And in the theory, it says I need a percentile for the hypothesis. Do I assume its 95%?

Comment: Is this from a textbook or a statistics course? If so, please name the source because it's a perfect illustration of how wonderfully irrelevant and misleading 'examples' can be. How and why and when would anyone in the real world want to test a hypothesis regarding a hypothesis that 50% of employees are happy?

Comment: @MichaelLew its a question on an exam that we were given for practice. So it's likely that it's made up by the professor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The null and alternative would be  $H_0: p = 0.5$ and $H_A: p \neq 0.5$.  Here, $p$ is the proportion of the population which are happy.
2. The standard deviation is a function of the sample proportion.  If you sample 100 people and 41 say they are happy, then $\hat{p}=0.41$ and $\hat{\sigma} = \sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}$.
3. I'm not sure what a "percentile for the hypothesis" means.  For a given hypothesis test, we have to decide on a false positive rate $\alpha$ which by convention is 0.05, but that is free to change.